# How to set the position of image

Tags: android

i am new in android , i am facing problem in setting the image position . i set image position in layout but when i check on device or emulator it changes position.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lay_ring"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backfull_a"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/id_ringButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/button_ring" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_hand_lastACt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/id_ring_finger"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"

    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/id_ringButton"
    android:src="@null" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/id_fingA_ring"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_imgback"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/a_style_a" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/id_fingB_ring"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_ringButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/id_fingA_ring"
    android:src="@drawable/a_style_b" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/id_next_ring"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/id_ringButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/id_ring_finger"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/aero_right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried but did not find proper solution . give some demo or link that is easily understandable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android handset has many DPIs. so,you should not set the position too accurate. 
You can use some relative description like `toRightof` / `alignPerentRight` etc.

Comment: but i think that will also change the position

Comment: It is impossible to let position unchanged in so many different handsets. However, what we want is only the position of general.For example, set the second one align Left, let three ImageViews have the same width and so on.

Comment: In addition,if you want to entirely control position.Just get screen width and height in java code,then set the position.